# Remove highlighting for a keyword in a single instance in lstlisting

Tags: multirow, lstlisting

I am using a custom `lstlisting` environment to highlight LaTeX Code. To use this I additionally entered a few more keywords. However, the `multirow` package uses its name as a command. How can I remove they keyword highlighting in this one instance just like on could do with `\mathrm` in a Math environment?

Here's the environment (reduced to the essentials):

```
\lstnewenvironment{customtex}
{\lstset{%
    language=[LaTeX]{TeX},
    ...
    keywordstyle=\color{darkred}\bfseries,
        morekeywords={multirow},
}}{}
```

And in the instance of `\RequirePackage{multirow}` the package should not be highlighted whereas when using `\multirow{...}{...}{...}` it should be highlighted as a keyword.

Comment: Welcome back to TeX.SE! I have answered your question with an MWE (minimal working example), which is a small but complete document that can be compiled and shows the behavior of the code. Next time when you write a question it would be helpful if you write such an MWE yourself, instead of only a small snippet. Of course it does not need to contain the solution, but it should contain everything else so it is easier for people that want to answer to start immediately on finding a solution without needing to write all the code around it.

Comment: Thank you for your help! And I surely will do that in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For listings with LaTeX code there are special `lstset` options that set the appearance of LaTeX commands and the corresponding options to add entries to the list of highlighted commands. These are `texcsstyle` (TeX Control Sequence Style) and `moretexcs`. If you want the backslash also highlighted (as it is done on this website for example) then you can use `=*` instead of `=`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\lstnewenvironment{customtex}
{\lstset{%
    language=[LaTeX]{TeX},
    texcsstyle=*\color{DarkRed}\bfseries,
    moretexcs={RequirePackage,multirow},
}}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{customtex}
\RequirePackage{multirow}
\multirow{1}{2}{3}
\end{customtex}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]